# expect with nested shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

I have a shell script batch_wrapper.sh which takes user input and it invokes another script  batch.sh.
These two script work perfectly fine.

Now, I have created a expect script test.sh which invokes batch_wrapper.sh and provides the input parameter. 
However, for some reason, batch.sh script is not getting invoked which I spawn batch_wrapper.sh from expect script. How can I fix this?

Sample expect script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 2000
spawn "./batch_wrapper.sh"
expect "username" {send "Vikas\r" }
```

Sample Shell Scripts are:

batch_wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter username"
read name
echo "your name is $name"
./batch.sh
```

batch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Inside batch"
echo "exiting batch"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script exits immediately afterwards as there's nothing left to do.

You can add `interact` or `expect eof {}` as the last line in your expect script to make it process the remainding output:

```
$ cat lol.expect 
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 2000
spawn "./batch_wrapper.sh"
expect "username" {send "Vikas\r" }
expect eof {}

$ expect -f lol.expect 
spawn ./batch_wrapper.sh
enter username
Vikas
your name is Vikas
Inside batch
exiting batch
```